# WordPress: Trying to get specific category url using "get_categories()"

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Okay, the problem is relatively simple just I not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Problem:

- I have 4 category menu i.e. Industry New, Management, Personal
  Development, Productivity' on the blog:
  http://radian3.com/blog/ (Click on one of the category to see what I mean, it should go to http://localhost/wordpress/category/industry-news/ example.

  - I need to retrieve each category' link so I can link each div to the correct url.

Currently the code below is NOT doing anything just refreshing the page (going to blog page)

```
            <div class="category-box">
        <?php 
            $categories = get_categories();
             $category_link = '';
            foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                if($cat->cat_name == 'industry news') {
                 $category_link = get_category_link($cat->cat_ID);
                }
                break;               
            }
        ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>"><img class="category-icon" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/desktop/images/category-icon-1.jpg">
            <h3> INDUSTRY NEWS</h3></a>
        </div>
```

Ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

Use `$cat->name` instead of `$cat->cat_name` and also change `$cat->cat_ID` to `$cat->term_id`

```
<div class="category-box">
<?php 
    $categories = get_categories();
    $category_link = '';
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->name == 'industry news') {
            $category_link = get_category_link($cat->term_id);
        }
        break;               
    }
?>

    <a href="<?php echo $category_link; ?>"><img class="category-icon" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/desktop/images/category-icon-1.jpg">
    <h3> INDUSTRY NEWS</h3></a>
</div>
```

**More info:** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

Comment: Ahh worked! syntax $cat->cate_name wrong? I watched it in a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach contains a `break` that's guaranteed to execute therefore you'll only ever have 1 iteration of the loop.

The markup is also outside of the loop which means it's showing once rather than for each category.

I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve so I'm going to provide two examples that I think will point you in the right direction.

### 1) Markup for each category

```
<?php $categories = get_categories();

if ( $categories ) {
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) { ?>

        <div class="category-box">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category ) ); ?>>
                <img class="category-icon" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/img/desktop/images/category-icon-1.jpg">
            </a>
            <h3><?php echo $category->name; ?></h3>
        </div>

    <?php }
}
```

If you go with this approach you'll still need to figure out how to update your image dynamically.

### 2) Get an array of links

Rather than getting a single link, we're going to get an array containing all category links.

```
<?php $categories = get_categories();

$category_links = array_map( function( $category ) {
    return get_category_link( $category );
}, $categories );

echo $category_links[0]; // [1], [2], etc...
```

While this works and will give you access to each of the links, I don't think it's an ideal solution. Instead you should be taking advantage of the data returned and displaying them dynamically rather than hardcoding.

If you're determined to go with option 2, perhaps adding some keys would help.

Example:

```
<?php $categories = get_categories();

$category_links = array();

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $category_links[ $category->slug ] = get_category_link( $category );
}
```

Usage:

```
<?php echo esc_url( $category_links['industry-news'] ); ?>
```

Keep in mind the example above uses slugs rather than names for the array keys.